# Python - Changing Url dynamically

Tags: python-3.x, url, dynamic

I am having a url defined in the variable like this:

```
req = Request('https://cex.io/api/ohlcv/hd/20180128/BTC/USD', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
```

I want the date i.e. **'20180128'** to be change daily in the url dynamically, like the next day it would become '20180129'.
Can it be possible?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the date in a variable and insert it into the middle of the url.

```
import datetime
date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d")
url = 'https://cex.io/api/ohlcv/hd/{}/BTC/USD'.format(date)
req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response, its a quite cool logic, but after writting the above mentioned code when im assigning 'req' variable into another variable named 'data' to store all the data in that variable and when im writting command,  print(data) it is showing as nonetype object.